# External callback - how do I then call back to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bitcoin

I have an website that takes in bitcoin donations and I want to be able to display some stats on the client browser once a donation has been made.

The Blockchain and Coinbase APIs both have an ability to call back to my Express server once a payment has been made to an address, but how do I then get the server to call back to the client so it can update itself with some new info?

Should I be looking at opening an AJAX request as soon as I display the bitcoin payment request on the client and wait for a callback? (I guess not seeing as the two sessions are independent). Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for the server to be able to notify the browser asynchronously, right?

That is a job for websockets. You can open a websocket connection when you display the payment request, and have it wait for the event to be sent from your server.

You will find a nice friendly intro to doing this with websockets [here](https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2010/02/10/json-event-based-convention-websockets/) which should help you get started.